# Pandas Dataframe line plot for weekly plot based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn

i have a dataframe with count for each year,month, and week for a type(a hue column):

```
Type    Year    Month      Week Count
Chat    2020    December    52  3
Chat    2020    December    53  3
Clinic  2020    December    52  433
Clinic  2020    December    53  245
Video   2020    December    52  115
Video   2020    December    53  69
Chat    2021    January     1   3
Chat    2021    January     2   7
Clinic  2021    January     1   500
Clinic  2021    January     2   200
Video   2021    January     1   50
Video   2021    January     2   20
```

I have to do a line plot for each type(dataframe column name) with y axis as the count and x axis december to January with the weeks also.

The plot should be from december 2020 to january 2021.

i'm trying to do plotly, but unable to achieve it.

my code:

```
fig = go.Figure()
        
        for appType, sub_data in temp.groupby('Appointment Type'):
            print(appType)
            tempX = sub_data['Month'].tolist()
            tempX.sort(reverse=True)
            tempY = sub_data['Count'].tolist()
            tempY.sort(reverse=True)
            
            fig.add_scatter(x=tempX, y=tempY, name=appType, mode='lines')
        
        fig.update_layout(
            title='Appointment Type-Overall - no.of.app={}|no.of.doctors={}'.format(sampleSize,sampleDoc),
            xaxis_title='Month of the Year',
            yaxis_title='Count',
            xaxis=dict(tickformat="%m")
            )
```

how to implement such use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your data into a pandas dataframe, first filter out only the rows required during the preferred timeframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_csv')
df = df[((df['Month'] == 'December') & (df['Year'] == 2020)) | ((df['Month'] == 'January') & (df['Year'] == 2021))]
```

Then use `groupby()` and `plot()` in pandas to get the desired result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.groupby(['Year','Week','Type']).Count.sum().unstack('Type').plot()
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: x axis labels is printing every second week. need to print all the x axis labels